# apps.jsb3 doesn't include controller definitions - when building

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I used the command `sencha create jsb -a http://myserver/myapp/app.html -p apps.jsb3 -v`

This created the file apps.jsb3, and when i opened this file, it contained all the definitions for Models and Stores (but, no controllers).

Then i followed with the command ;

`sencha build -p apps.jsb3 -v -d .` and this created 2 files. app.all.js which is a compressed form of the model, store and the app.js (and it also includes the definition of the controllers of the application as found in the app.js)

ex : `....controllers:["Person","Pers...` likewise

and then `all-classes.js` has all the models, and stores (and again no controllers)

Then i included the following to my app.html file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/ext.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app-all.js"></script>
```

Finally, i copied the app-all.js, all-classes.js, app.html to another folder in the server. and this folder is called `SERVERFOLDER2`.

Now, when i type `http://myserver/SERVERFOLDER2/app.html` it says that `"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://myserver/SERVERFOLDER2/app/controller/Person.js?_dc=1347636548640"`.

Why is this, and how can i resolve this ?

**UPDATE APP.JS**

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true     
});
Ext.require('Ext.container.Viewport' );  
Ext.application({        
    requires: [                     
        'MyApp.Names',          
        'Ext.window.MessageBox'   
    ],                         
       models: [      
        'PersonModel',      
        'SchoolModel'                 
    ],     
    stores: [ 
        'PersonStore',
        'SchoolStore'  ,
        'GenderStore
    ],     
    views: [            
        'UserPanel',      
        'SchoolViewPanel',               
        'UpdateSchoolWindow' 
    ],            
    controllers: [        
        'SchoolController',    
        'PersonController',      
        'UserActionController',
    ],     
     name: 'MyApp', 
    refs: 
        [{         
            ref: 'viewport',   
            selector: 'viewport'
        }],     
    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {  
        layout: 'card',  
            items: [  
            { 
                xtype: 'panel',        
                items: {
                xtype: 'UserPanel' 
                }
            }
            ]
        });  

    },

    userSuccess: function() {  
        var st = Ext.getStore('PersonStore');         
        st.on('load', this.onSuccess, this, {    
            single: true,  
            delay: 100            
        }); 
        st.load();      
    },            

    onSuccess: function() {      
        this.getViewport().getLayout().setActiveItem(1); 
    }

});
```

Comment: Please update your post with your **app.js** codes.

Comment: I have added my `app.js` to my post. Please have a look.

Comment: You get an error that is related to **"controller/Person.js"** but there is no such file in your **controller** of **app.js**. Am I wrong?

Comment: sorry i forgot to include it above. the file is there in the app.js

Comment: I suggest you to simplify your project as much as you can. For example without stores, models, refs but controllers. Then build your project until you see your controller class in **apps.jsb3**. After that paste your deleted codes step by step and see where is the problem exactly come from.

Comment: Another suggestion is to put **-v** option at the end of your **sencha build** command to see the details. Maybe it has built with some errors. Your command will look like this (When you are in Root of your MyApp folder): **sencha create jsb -a index.html -p app.jsb3 -v** (and be sure to use the latest version of sdk tools which is **2.0.0-beta3**)

Comment: oh yes, i did that. but i used `http://server/proj/app.html` instead of index.html. no errors were thrown

Comment: I am confused as well: do you have both a class/file `MyApp.controller.PersonController` **and** a class `MyApp.controller.Person`? 
Also consider that class namespace and directory structure have to map (with the exception of the top level namespace 'MyApp' being matched to the directory 'app' unless you configure the applicaton's 'appFolder' property differently)

Comment: The namespace is `MyApp` and the folder that contains all the model,views and controllers is named `app`. The application launches perfectly, but the controllers are not included in the .jsb3 file. I found a similar problem in the net > http://goo.gl/grBWn

Comment: You include `Person` in the 'models' collection which will/should resolve to `MyApp.model.Person`, but say that the error message states
>http://../app/controller/Person.js?_dc=1347636548640"
It tries to load `MyApp.controller.Person`. Something is not right here.

Comment: The forum posts describes a scenario where controllers are not loaded on application launch, but later on during application runtime. This use-case is not supported by Sencha's SDK Tools. It will only collect dependencies loaded during application launch. Any dependencies loaded as response to a user reaction will **not** be detected.
I am not sure that scenario is similar to yours.

Comment: I have corrected it. I made a mistake and now `Person` should read as `PersonModel`

Comment: These inconsistencies between your code and your question make it difficult for others to give advise. You fixed one but it it seems you have a similar thing going on with PersonController (MyApp.controller.Person?). Your class names MUST match the filename, otherwise Ext.Loader will fail.
My last advise is to use fully qualified names in your app definition: add `MyApp.controller.PersonController` instead of just `PersonController`. 
I also noticed that you opened another question on your problem. So maybe you have better luck there. I am outta here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process you describe looks good to me.

The problem you should focus on is why the generated jsb3 file does't include the controller classes. All the steps that follow seem to work correctly, but the application does not fire up in the end because the packaging process does not include your controller class files.

Ext.Loader kicks in and tries to dynamically ('on demand') load the controller class file - the goal here is **not** to fix the path configuration for Ext.Loader to find the controller class, but rather to make sure the controller classes are included in the `jsb3` file from step 1 in the first place.

I assume that your application starts up fine when launching it via `http://myserver/myapp/app.html` in the non-packaged state (with only `ext-dev.js` and no `ext-all.js`, `app.all.js` or whatsoever).

I further assume that you can observe messages on the console that say something along the lines of:

> Synchronously loading 'app.controller.Person'. Consider adding Ext.require() above Ext.onReady

This means that your class dependencies are not configured correctly. The controller class is **not** picked up as dependency and therefore **not** pre-loaded before your application starts.

The packaging process (your first step) relies on the dependencies to generate the `jsb3` file. It will **not** pick up dependencies loaded synchronously on demand.

**Solution**
The goal is to remove **any** synchronous on-demand loading when you start your application. If you are successful, the packaging process should be fixed as well.

As a quick workaround you could simply `Ext.require` your controller classes above your `Ext.onReady` or `Ext.application` call.

However, controller classes **should** be automatically added as dependency by the framework. If they are not, then either your configuration is faulty or there it is a bug in ExtJs.

Comment: I don't get the `Synchronously loading ...` error message. Anyway, should i include the controller as `Ext.require('MyApplication.controller.PersonController' ); `? with the full path of the file `'MyApplication.controller.PersonController' ` ?

Comment: After adding all the controllers as `Ext.require('MyApplication.controller.PersonController' );` i still get the same output.

Comment: That is odd. 
You didn't answer my question whether you can launch your application successfully with `http://server/proj/app.html` in the browser? Forget about the packaging. As I said: if your application doesn't launch correctly, packaging will fail as well.

Comment: The app launches perfectly. Everything works fine. It's only that the controllers doesn't get included in the .jsb3 file.